# Gradle init project not able to add dependencies to "app" subproject

Tags: java, gradle

I created a new Gradle 8.1.1 project with `gradle init` chosing the options application (2), Java (3), no multiple subprojects, Groovy DSL, JUnit 5,the same project and source package name and Java 11.

I added Apache Commons to app/build.gradle and wanted called StringUtils in App.java but it failed. I first thought VS Code had an issue, but running `./gradlew build` fails also with:

```
gradle-basic-structure-dep-error\app\src\main\java\gradle\basic\structure\dep\error\App.java:10: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to String
        return StringUtils.isBlank("  ");
                                  ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is the full example: https://github.com/cwansart/gradle-basic-structure-dep-error

Why is it failing? Might this be an error in the generated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the issue: in VS Code the imports were marked red and not find, regardless of the error I did mentioned by Jeremie.

I tried it on a different computer on which it worked. I tried it again on my working machine in a new profile with a clean checkout and it worked again. It seems that the Java or Gradle VSCode plugin had an issue, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the return type of `getGreeting()` is `String`, and return type of `StringUtils.isBlank("  ")` is a `boolean`.
So you should change the return type like below

```
public boolean getGreeting() {
    return StringUtils.isBlank("  ");
}
```

Beside, you should write java code using IDE like Intelij or Eclipse. It will highlight and report this kind of error for you

Comment: You're right, I mixed up the error in the terminal. VS Code has highlighting, but it is unable to find the dependencies and thus showing a different error. I'll check that. Thanks

Comment: When you updated your project configuration (build.gradle), you need to right click the build.gradle file and select 'Reload Project'. Or set the setting `java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration` to `automatic`